# InfiniDB table size calculation

Tags: infinidb

I am trying to figure out the table size for an infiniDB table.

In `Show TABLE STATUS` i see the data size as 0

Answer (score 1):

The only way to find out the tables' and columns' size is to run the databaseSizeReport utility. It reports the physical size, in gigabytes, of the data existing on the dbroots.
But this feature is only available with Calpont InfiniDB Enterprise.

Comment: the untility is included in the 4.6.x open source editions.